# How does the "||=" operator differ from "?=" in CoffeeScript?

Tags: operators, coffeescript, assignment-operator

What is the difference between these two? From Ruby, I am used to `apple ||= walrus` setting apple equal to walrus only if apple is null. That seems to be the same in JS/CS, though ?= seems to do the same thing. What confuses me is this:

```
apple = 0
walrus = 9
apple ?= walrus // outputs 0
apple ||= walrus // outputs 9
```

wat

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to look at the resulting JS.

Coffeescript:

```
apple = 0
walrus = 9
apple ?= walrus // outputs 0
apple ||= walrus // outputs 9
```

JavaScript:

```
var apple, walrus;
apple = 0;
walrus = 9;
if (apple == null) apple = walrus;
apple || (apple = walrus);
```

As you can see, the `?=` explicitly checks is something is `null` or `undefined` in JS. This is very different from `||=` which just relies on whether `apple` is a falsy value.

To expand a bit more `apple ||= walrus` is equivalent in meaning to `apple = apple || walrus`, so any value of apple that is truthy will short-circuit the logic and not change the value of apple.

Comment: That last line got me to understand it. Thank you.

Comment: (For the casual reader: `undefined == null` is true in JavaScript. `undefined` and `null`, two false-y values, are the *only* values of `x` which result in `x == null` being true.)

Comment: @loganfsmyth It could have done much worse ... it has first-class functions and closures (some languages are a *long* way from here) ;-)

Comment: @pst Oh definitely. I like JS a lot, but it still has it's quirks.

Comment: Note that `apple ?= walrus` could also be used as an expression `x = apple ?= walrus` (everything is an expression in CoffeeScript) and in this case will compile to `x = apple != null ? apple : apple = walrus;`.

Answer (score 4):

`?=` is the **existential** operator. It checks against `null` and `undefined`.

`||=` just checks the variable's value to be "not false", if I remember right... so that means `0` is false.